# PHP Memcached expiration time

Tags: php, memcached

I've got a problem with Memcached. I'm on Debian 8 and using PHP7. `phpinfo()` returns me this version of `memcached` : `3.0.0b1`. I can store and get values, everything is OK. The problem is that I would like to store a value with an expiration time but that doesn't work.
What I've tried so far:

```
 $memcached = new Memcached();
 $memcached->set('key','value',10);
 $memcached->set('key','value',time()+10);
 //waiting more than 10 sec
 $data = $memcached->getAllKeys();
 var_dump($data);
 // all keys are here :'(
```

Any suggestions?

**edit** A new test : still not working (keys are here)

```
$memcached = new Memcached();
$memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1',11211);
$memcached->set('key','value',10);
$memcached->set('key','value',time()+10);
sleep(20); //waiting more than 20 sec

$data = $memcached->getAllKeys();
var_dump($data);
// all keys are here :'(
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur answer, but the documentation say : public bool Memcached::set ( string $key , mixed $value [, int $expiration ] ), if its the 4th, what is the 3rd ?

Comment: After consulting the documentation, i think you are talking about **memcach** but im using **memcached** :'(

Comment: does not work it means that does not expire or that you get an error?

Comment: It does not expire, im still getting values

Comment: if you found the answer, create a response and post it as a reference for people that will search in the future for the same problem. If you think this was something unique, ask to delete the post

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will do it, but for the moment it does not expire ... Should i use memcach instead of memcached ? Is there a compatible version with PHP7 ?

Comment: Is this the whole script? in this script you are setting the key and checking for the value right away. add a `sleep(20)` after the `$memcached->set(...)`

Comment: and the first version is correct (10 sec), unless you have more than 30 days than you have to use timestamps

Comment: I've edited the post with a new test but still not working ...

Comment: You do not have other errors in your logs?

Comment: sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/access.log : everythings looks normal

Comment: Instead of `getAllKeys()`, try to `get()` the key that you set. It might not expire the element until you actually try to retrieve it.

Comment: You are rigth @Barmar this is the solution, Thank you all !

Comment: @Barmar good catch

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all, the solution was (from @Barmar) :

Instead of `getAllKeys()`, try to `get()` the key that you set. It might not expire the element until you actually try to retrieve it.

Comment: There is an interesting note that says that `getAllKeys` is not an atomic operation and does not guarantee that all keys that it returns are still active. http://no2.php.net/manual/en/memcached.getallkeys.php